# Wordpress multisite and redirect

Tags: nginx, hosting, wordpress, php-cgi

I come to you because I'm facing a really strange effect on my hosting.

I currently manage a server contening a NGINX/PHP-CGI and a wordpress multisite in it.

My sites are created using subsite.domaine.tld, for now, my three subsites are correctly accessibles through the url:

```
subsite.domain.tld.
```

My goal is to allow my subsite on the host domain to be access through their respective unique domain.

For exemple:

```
www.domainA.com would redirect to subsite1.host.domain.tld.
```

If I do that using the following setting on the domainA Public DNS:

```
www 10800 IN CNAME subsite1.host.domain.tld.
```

When I try to access www.domainA.com I don't go to subsite1.host.domain.tld but instead I'm redirect to the Wordpress ROOT site where I create my Network (host.domain.tld).

Is there a trick to deal with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the WordPress [domain mapping](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) plugin. Otherwise WordPress has no idea which blog to use to service the request.